# Add radio button to windows form datagrid control

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I have DataGrid on my windows form, I am adding a row to DataGrid at runtime. I have a column on DataGrid to which I need to add different UI control(each cell of a column will contain different UI controls like dropdown, checkbox, hyperlink, radio button) at runtime. I can add other controls except for radio button control, how can I add a radio button to DataGrid column?
I have used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882%28VS.80%29.aspx) its not working for me as it requires the whole column as radio button column.

Comment: What is the purpose of using it? Radiobutton is used so that when there is a few options you select one only. If you only want it to be used on a per row basis you should use a checkbox

Comment: I would recommend using a checkbox if there is just one option to select.

Comment: I have updated question by adding image, that's what i need in grid.

Answer (score 0):

Here a how can make a Column of checkboxes work as RadioButtons. From your picture you need a one Row with all columns as RadioBUttons -> this is more complicated and independs on how your binding data to datagridview. I working more with VB.NET so here may be some syntax errors...

Create a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column in your datagridview
With three Events of DataGridView my checkbox column work as a radiobutton

```
private Boolean bRbtnCurrentValue 
private Int32 iColumnRadioBtn = 4
private Datagridview dgv //Only for this exapmle

//In Event dgv_CellBeginEdit
{
    //Here we stored current value to variable
    if (this.dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = this.iColumnRadioBtn)
        this.bRbtnCurrentValue = this.dgv
}

//In Event dgv_CellEndEdit
{
    //Here we update if value changed
    Boolean bNewValue = this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value
    if (this.dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = this.iColumnRadioBtn)
    {
        if(bNewValue=False)
            this.dgv.CurrentCell.Value=this.bRbtnCurrentValue
        else
            //Here jo actions when value changed(database update etc.)
    }   
}

//Event dgv_ CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
{
    if(this.dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = this.iColumnRadioBtn) andalso (dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty = True)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr In dgv.Rows)
        {
            If (dgvr.Index = dgv.CurrentRow.Index)
                If (dgv.CurrentCell.Value = True)
                    dgv.CancelEdit() //True to False cannot be changed
            else
                If (dgvr.Cells(dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Value=True)
                    dgvr.Cells(dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Value = False
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you told i should ceate DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn , but in my application  column can also contain cotrols like combo , textbox and hyperlink. so i cant add DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn , i want to add different controls to each cell of column.